# Powershell unicode chars in string

Tags: powershell

I have read Microsoft powershell official documentation and i've found this example:

```
"`u{0048}"
```

It should display an H

But, i my case, it displays:

> u{0048}

I do not need alternatives, i want to understand why it does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `` `u{XXXX} `` escape sequence was added to the string expansion grammar in PowerShell 6, and will not be recognized as such in *any version* of Windows PowerShell.

---

In Windows PowerShell you can cast the numerical value to `[char]` in a sub-expression:

```
"$([char]0x48)"
```

Or use the `-as` operator to convert to `[char]`:

```
0x48 -as [char]
# or
0x48 -as 'char'
```

If you're trying to produce the `[char]` value `H` without using `h`, `H`, `[` or `]` in the source code, there are plenty of opportunities in PowerShell, `ForEach-Object`'s aliases and member-invocation-via-wildcards is especially handy:

```
# grab the `h` in `$env:path`
(dir env:pat?).Name.GetEnumerator()|select -Last 1

# reflect against another existing [char] to get the type
$g = 'g'|% ToC?ar ($null)
0x48 -as $g.GetType()

# generate char range between G and I, filter out G and I (pwsh >6.1 only)
'G'..'I'|?{$_-notin'G','I'}
```

Comment: I am working on a CTF challenge and i am not allowed to type [ char. Is there a way to do this with out brackets ? Thanks..

Comment: @Bob5421 Do an unchecked cast with the target type name as a string: `0x48 -as 'char'`

Comment: h char is forbidden too :)

Comment: Well, then you'll have to figure out a way to obtain some reference to a `[char]` type or the string `char` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot but it does not work: I have a fewer version than 6.1, i cannot type - or ( but i can type { }

Comment: @Bob5421 I'm not gonna update this answer any further until you _update [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63636639/edit) with ALL the relevant details_

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have answered to my initial question: The reason was i have a fewer version. My comments are off-topic i am sorry i will create another question